# Resolving Eigen Matrix Matching Function Error

Tags: ros, pcl, eigen, eigen3

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I run catkin_make I get the following error:

```
In file included from /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/Core:458,
                 from /usr/include/pcl-1.10/pcl/pcl_macros.h:75,
                 from /usr/include/pcl-1.10/pcl/console/parse.h:43,
                 from /home/shivam/catkin_ws/src/pcl_tutorial/src/random_sample_consensus.cpp:4:
/usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/Matrix.h: In instantiation of ‘Eigen::Matrix<_Scalar, _Rows, _Cols, _Options, _MaxRows, _MaxCols>::Matrix(const T0&, const T1&) [with T0 = Eigen::Matrix<float, 4, 1>; T1 = int; _Scalar = float; int _Rows = 4; int _Cols = 1; int _Options = 0; int _MaxRows = 4; int _MaxCols = 1]’:
/home/shivam/catkin_ws/src/pcl_tutorial/src/random_sample_consensus.cpp:372:66:   required from here
/usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/Matrix.h:302:35: error: no matching function for call to ‘Eigen::Matrix<float, 4, 1>::_init2<Eigen::Matrix<float, 4, 1, 0, 4, 1>, int>(const Eigen::Matrix<float, 4, 1>&, const int&)’
  302 |       Base::template _init2<T0,T1>(x, y);
      |       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/Core:457,
                 from /usr/include/pcl-1.10/pcl/pcl_macros.h:75,
                 from /usr/include/pcl-1.10/pcl/console/parse.h:43,
                 from /home/shivam/catkin_ws/src/pcl_tutorial/src/random_sample_consensus.cpp:4:
/usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/PlainObjectBase.h:738:30: note: candidate: ‘void Eigen::PlainObjectBase<Derived>::_init2(Eigen::Index, Eigen::Index, typename Eigen::internal::enable_if<(typename Eigen::internal::dense_xpr_base<Derived>::type::SizeAtCompileTime != 2), T0>::type*) [with T0 = Eigen::Matrix<float, 4, 1>; T1 = int; Derived = Eigen::Matrix<float, 4, 1>; Eigen::Index = long int; typename Eigen::internal::enable_if<(typename Eigen::internal::dense_xpr_base<Derived>::type::SizeAtCompileTime != 2), T0>::type = Eigen::Matrix<float, 4, 1>]’
  738 |     EIGEN_STRONG_INLINE void _init2(Index rows, Index cols, typename internal::enable_if<Base::SizeAtCompileTime!=2,T0>::type* = 0)
      |                              ^~~~~~
/usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/PlainObjectBase.h:738:43: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const Eigen::Matrix<float, 4, 1>’ to ‘Eigen::Index’ {aka ‘long int’}
  738 |     EIGEN_STRONG_INLINE void _init2(Index rows, Index cols, typename internal::enable_if<Base::SizeAtCompileTime!=2,T0>::type* = 0)
      |                                     ~~~~~~^~~~
/usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/PlainObjectBase.h:748:30: note: candidate: ‘template<class T0, class T1> void Eigen::PlainObjectBase<Derived>::_init2(const T0&, const T1&, typename Eigen::internal::enable_if<(typename Eigen::internal::dense_xpr_base<Derived>::type::SizeAtCompileTime == 2), T0>::type*) [with T0 = T0; T1 = T1; Derived = Eigen::Matrix<float, 4, 1>]’
  748 |     EIGEN_STRONG_INLINE void _init2(const T0& val0, const T1& val1, typename internal::enable_if<Base::SizeAtCompileTime==2,T0>::type* = 0)
      |                              ^~~~~~
/usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/PlainObjectBase.h:748:30: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/PlainObjectBase.h: In substitution of ‘template<class T0, class T1> void Eigen::PlainObjectBase<Eigen::Matrix<float, 4, 1> >::_init2<T0, T1>(const T0&, const T1&, typename Eigen::internal::enable_if<false, T0>::type*) [with T0 = Eigen::Matrix<float, 4, 1>; T1 = int]’:
/usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/Matrix.h:302:35:   required from ‘Eigen::Matrix<_Scalar, _Rows, _Cols, _Options, _MaxRows, _MaxCols>::Matrix(const T0&, const T1&) [with T0 = Eigen::Matrix<float, 4, 1>; T1 = int; _Scalar = float; int _Rows = 4; int _Cols = 1; int _Options = 0; int _MaxRows = 4; int _MaxCols = 1]’
/home/shivam/catkin_ws/src/pcl_tutorial/src/random_sample_consensus.cpp:372:66:   required from here
/usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/PlainObjectBase.h:748:30: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct Eigen::internal::enable_if<false, Eigen::Matrix<float, 4, 1> >’
In file included from /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/Core:364,
                 from /usr/include/pcl-1.10/pcl/pcl_macros.h:75,
                 from /usr/include/pcl-1.10/pcl/console/parse.h:43,
                 from /home/shivam/catkin_ws/src/pcl_tutorial/src/random_sample_consensus.cpp:4:
/usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/util/Meta.h:184:50: note: declaration of ‘struct Eigen::internal::enable_if<false, Eigen::Matrix<float, 4, 1> >’
  184 | template<bool Condition, typename T=void> struct enable_if;
      |                                                  ^~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/Core:457,
                 from /usr/include/pcl-1.10/pcl/pcl_macros.h:75,
                 from /usr/include/pcl-1.10/pcl/console/parse.h:43,
                 from /home/shivam/catkin_ws/src/pcl_tutorial/src/random_sample_consensus.cpp:4:
/usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/Matrix.h: In instantiation of ‘Eigen::Matrix<_Scalar, _Rows, _Cols, _Options, _MaxRows, _MaxCols>::Matrix(const T0&, const T1&) [with T0 = Eigen::Matrix<float, 4, 1>; T1 = int; _Scalar = float; int _Rows = 4; int _Cols = 1; int _Options = 0; int _MaxRows = 4; int _MaxCols = 1]’:
/home/shivam/catkin_ws/src/pcl_tutorial/src/random_sample_consensus.cpp:372:66:   required from here
/usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/PlainObjectBase.h:757:30: note: candidate: ‘template<class T0, class T1> void Eigen::PlainObjectBase<Derived>::_init2(const Index&, const Index&, typename Eigen::internal::enable_if<((((! Eigen::internal::is_same<long int, typename Eigen::internal::traits<T>::Scalar>::value) && Eigen::internal::is_same<T0, long int>::value) && Eigen::internal::is_same<T1, long int>::value) && (typename Eigen::internal::dense_xpr_base<Derived>::type::SizeAtCompileTime == 2)), T1>::type*) [with T0 = T0; T1 = T1; Derived = Eigen::Matrix<float, 4, 1>]’
  757 |     EIGEN_STRONG_INLINE void _init2(const Index& val0, const Index& val1,
      |                              ^~~~~~
/usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/PlainObjectBase.h:757:30: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/PlainObjectBase.h: In substitution of ‘template<class T0, class T1> void Eigen::PlainObjectBase<Eigen::Matrix<float, 4, 1> >::_init2<T0, T1>(const Index&, const Index&, typename Eigen::internal::enable_if<((((! Eigen::internal::is_same<long int, float>::value) && Eigen::internal::is_same<T0, long int>::value) && Eigen::internal::is_same<T1, long int>::value) && (Eigen::MatrixBase<Eigen::Matrix<float, 4, 1> >::SizeAtCompileTime == 2)), T1>::type*) [with T0 = Eigen::Matrix<float, 4, 1>; T1 = int]’:
/usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/Matrix.h:302:35:   required from ‘Eigen::Matrix<_Scalar, _Rows, _Cols, _Options, _MaxRows, _MaxCols>::Matrix(const T0&, const T1&) [with T0 = Eigen::Matrix<float, 4, 1>; T1 = int; _Scalar = float; int _Rows = 4; int _Cols = 1; int _Options = 0; int _MaxRows = 4; int _MaxCols = 1]’
/home/shivam/catkin_ws/src/pcl_tutorial/src/random_sample_consensus.cpp:372:66:   required from here
/usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/PlainObjectBase.h:757:30: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct Eigen::internal::enable_if<false, int>’
In file included from /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/Core:364,
                 from /usr/include/pcl-1.10/pcl/pcl_macros.h:75,
                 from /usr/include/pcl-1.10/pcl/console/parse.h:43,
                 from /home/shivam/catkin_ws/src/pcl_tutorial/src/random_sample_consensus.cpp:4:
/usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/util/Meta.h:184:50: note: declaration of ‘struct Eigen::internal::enable_if<false, int>’
  184 | template<bool Condition, typename T=void> struct enable_if;
      |                                                  ^~~~~~~~~
make[2]: *** [pcl_tutorial/CMakeFiles/random_sample_consensus.dir/build.make:63: pcl_tutorial/CMakeFiles/random_sample_consensus.dir/src/random_sample_consensus.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:11799: pcl_tutorial/CMakeFiles/random_sample_consensus.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:141: all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j8 -l8" failed
```

I am using the Eigen library in my code and I have included the following Eigen header files:

```
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <Eigen/Core>
```

I also tried to change CMakeLists.txt to include the Eigen library, but I got the same error. Here are the few lines I added when nothing worked:

```
find_package (Eigen3 3.4 REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(random_sample_consensus ${catkin_LIBRARIES} pcl_visualization Eigen3::Eigen)
```

If you want to see the full CMakelist.txt and package.xml I am using please refer to [this](https://answers.ros.org/question/392399/how-to-resolve-fatal-error-transform_listenerh-no-such-file-or-directory/) post. I don't want to make this post too long.

I also tried installing the latest Eigen library from [this](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) link by following the instructions provided on [this](https://tutorialforlinux.com/2020/09/25/step-by-step-eigen-c-ubuntu-20-04-installation-guide/2/) website.

My code runs without any errors, but catkin_make is giving errors. I would appreciate any help to resolve this error.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/392538/how-to-resolve-%22error:-no-matching-function-for-call-to-%E2%80%98eigen::matrix%3Cfloat,-4,-1%3E::_init2%3Ceigen::matrix%3Cfloat,-4,-1,-0,-4,-1%3E,-int%3E(const-eigen::matrix%3Cfloat,-4,-1%3E&,-const-int&)%E2%80%99%22?/) by [Shivam](https://answers.ros.org/users/84595/shivam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 66 on 2021-12-09

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2021-12-09**:
Looks Eigen installation is ok but the problem is with a conversion. Check this prior answer: https://answers.ros.org/question/339005/error-using-eigen/

**Comment by [Shivam](https://answers.ros.org/users/84595/shivam/) on 2021-12-10**:
@osilva I resolved the error. The problem was in the cpp file. I was passing the wrong data type to an Eigen function. I don't why the visual studio code didn't show any error when I open that file. It generally shows these types of errors in the editor itself. So I thought this was a dependency error but it is not.

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2021-12-10**:
Glad you found the answer and thank you for recording the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I resolved the error. The problem was in the cpp file. I was passing the wrong data type to an Eigen function. I don't why the visual studio code didn't show any error when I open that file. It generally shows these types of errors in the editor itself. So I thought this was a dependency error but it is not.

---

Originally posted by [Shivam](https://answers.ros.org/users/84595/shivam/) with karma: 66 on 2021-12-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1